# Several user-space programs mmap() to same physical memory address?

Tags: linux, memory, mmap

I would like to write a few user-space programs to mmap the same physical address (sharing resource).

```
md = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR|O_SYNC);  
if (md == -1) {  printf("Can't open /dev/mem\n"); return (-1);  }

map_base = mmap(0, 1024*1024, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, md, mmioAddr);
```

where mmioAddr is the physical address that I need to mmap.

Will there be a problem if several user programs do this?
Do I need some kinds of mutex to protect the shared resource?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use shm?

Comment: Did you try it?  What happened?